# Converting inArray() to JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have the following function that makes use of jQuery's inArray() function

```
function initialStrandOptions() {
  if($('#component_id_1').prop('checked') == true){
    var strand_options = $('.strand_options').find('option');
      strand_options.each(function(){
        if( jQuery.inArray($(this).val(), ['4', '5', '6', '7']) != -1 ){
          $(this).hide();
        }
      });  
   } 
}
```

So as you can see this is saying that for each value check whether we have a match in the array (-1), if there's no match (or just != -1) then hide that option.

I am looking to re-write this in JavaScript (I don't want to depend on jQuery) but it's been a while since I've done any pure JavaScript. I know I can use `indexOf()`.

### Update

Based on the comments and answers I don't think I have explained what I want to achieve fully. Within the function I don't want to use any jQuery at all (not just the `inArray` function). I want to find out how to construct a function or two using JavaScript alone.

Comment: try using arrayname.indexOf("arrayitemtobecmpared");

Comment: So you know the javascript method, what specifically do you need assistance with? Finding the [documentation perhaps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)?

Comment: "I know I can use indexOf()" - Yes, please do.

Answer (score 2):

The `$.inArray()` method is similar to JavaScript's native `.indexOf()` method in that it returns -1 when it doesn't find a match. If the first element within the array matches value, `$.inArray()` returns 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
function inArray(needle, haystack) {
  if (haystack.indexOf(needle) !== -1) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L338) of jquery, you will see that they use `indexOf` in they `inArray` function. Like this:

```
inArray: function( elem, arr, i ) {
    return arr == null ? -1 : indexOf.call( arr, elem, i );
}
```